# SocialEngine: Update password with Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract::save()

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I am calling `save()` on a database item after assigning a value to `$item->password`. The problem is that it updates the database field weirdly. A string other than what I am assigning is saved. Check the code:

```
    if ($password == $passwordConfirm && $password != NULL) {
        //Save the password in db
        $settings = Engine_Api::_()->getApi('settings', 'core');
        $staticSalt = $settings->getSetting('core.secret', 'staticSalt');
        $user = Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable('user')->fetchRow(['phone_number=?' => $this->session->phone, 'account_recovery=?' => $this->session->recoveryCode]);
        $userSalt = $user->salt;
        $dbPassword = md5($staticSalt . $password . $userSalt);
        $user->password = $dbPassword;
        $user->save();
        $this->view->form->addNotice(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->_('Password updated'));
        echo  $this->session->recoveryCode  . ', ' . $staticSalt . '  . ' . $password . ' . ' . $userSalt . ' dbpassword:  ' . $dbPassword . ', ' . $user->password;
    }
```

Output of echo:

```
 41d53c78ace54bef39a4d22749447a8f, 06eebbd766133fda10c526e9fad2da6c84df0597 . a@a.com . 4826122 dbpassword: c2cec82096e9b89a22961cf5f70be639, 06af9074fbd95452c2a01603ec54cb58
```

You see that the calculated password, which I assume is correct, is different than the password that is saved in the database. Is there any special consideration I need to keep in mind before calling `save()` like casting the value or something?

I just found out that I don't need to call `save()` for the database table to be updated. In fact, calling `save()` after assigning a value to a column saves a weird value. I tried commenting out `save` and then reading the value. This time, the password column is correctly updated with the calculated password. But, again, my problem is that the password cannot be used to login. For example, if the user password that I use to calculate the database password is `abcdabcd`, I cannot log in to the account with that password. I might be missing something on how user authentication is done in SocialEngine.

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, it is what SocialEngine uses by default for hashing passwords. The formula it uses is `$password = md5($secretSalt, $inputPassword, $userSalt)`.

Comment: It's still insecure and any software that uses it,should be patched or not used. It puts your users passwords at risk.